# Cannot pass Leverage browser caching (PageSpeed Insights)

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, browser, external

I manage the external javascript in my page as below

```
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?publisherid=100802427533778671877"/></script
    <script async src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5439942003ee228c"/></script>
    <script async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"/></script>                                   
    <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"/></script>
    <script src="/scripts/common/social.js"/></script>
```

Here the reports from [PageSpeed Insights](http://goo.gl/833sQy):

Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

```
http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js (5 minutes)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/…v/www/scripts/tools/mobile-detect.min.js (5 minutes)
http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js (10 minutes)
http://widgets.pinterest.com/…callback=PIN_1414678084159.f.callback[0] (14.8 minutes)
http://cdn.syndication.twitter.com/…ophyips.info&callback=twttr.receiveCount (15 minutes)
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js (20 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/…orm.js?publisherid=100802427533778671877 (30 minutes)
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js (4.8 hours)
```

How to pass this as I run those script in the Google Appeengine (cannot set httpd.conf of Apache).

Comment: I ended up serving all css and js files from my server rather than cdn. Got 100/100 on page speed with that approach :)

Comment: Do yo mean convert all external js or css and serve as local files on your server?

Comment: Yes, I actually use a grunt file to automate the task of concatinating all js/css files into one single js/css file, and minifying it. The downside is of course that you have to handle updates manually.